# Can I use the Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize a local ms access (mdb) database against SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, microsoft-sync-framework

I see variations of this question have been asked a couple of times, but none of the answers seemed to be definitive.

I'm looking for a yes/no as to whether the sync framework will accept Access database files as a data provider/client without inefficient and complicated workarounds.

I tried reading through the Microsoft documentation, but at a certain point it became Alice In Wonderland.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: totally agree with "Alice in wonderland". she probably was more sober than i am right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, No, not out of the box.

You would have to write your own [Custom Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937537%28SQL.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.

Comment: @RyanWeir Did you ever finished writing your custom provider? Are you kindly able to share the code?